# How to create listing on google apps marketplace?

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

I'm new to google apps marketplace and not getting how to create marketplace listing?

On Google Apps Marketplace top page, click "My Vendor Profile"
Click "Create your first listing" button, but button is not clickable.

and moreover on clicking on become vendor it redirecting me on

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/developer/dashboard, instead of createVendorProfile. Please help me.

Thank you,
Jaya Rai

Answer (score 1):

I believe Google Apps Marketplace page will slowly be deprecated. The process to create a listing has recently changed. See http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.in/2013/11/your-apps-google-apps-awesome.html.

Thanks,
-Gagan

Comment: Thanks Gagan, I have been gone through the new documentation but in new documentation they have not described about charges like $100 so i just wanted to know weather i have to pay it or not as u know it is non refundable. And d main problem is that i'm not able to get how to create listing and set price for my application.

Jaya Rai

Comment: Where are $100 charges mentioned? AFAIK there is jut one time developer signup fee of $5 for publishing to Chrome Webstore.